# Handle server side redirection on react application

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect, oauth-2.0

Currently I have a react application with the login done with OAuth2 Authorization Code PKCE flow in the back-end. on successfully submitting the login credentials the server redirects to a redirectURI with the authorization code as a url parameter. currently I have a created a matching route in the front-end, but the redirection is not happening. Is there any possible way to handle this redirection from the front-end using react?

Below is the ss of the requests
[image: ss network tab]
[image: login]
[image: redirected URL]

The redirected URL throws 404 not found error, even though a route matching the redirected URL is present in the react-router-dom (<Route path="/account-info/" element = { } />).

Comment: Am I reading correctly here that the OAuth2 endpoint is redirecting back to the app, but the server hosting the app is returning a 404 to the browser that the page isn't found/doesn't exist? Is the server configured to serve the root index.html file for all page requests?

Comment: @DrewReese currently I am running the react app on http://localhost:3001/. how can I configure it to serve the index.html for all page requests? I have not done that before.

Comment: So you are currently using a local build? How are you running the app locally? Can you share your scripts? See [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese I am running the react application using react-scripts start and the back-end (.Net) is running using the docker container.

Comment: @DrewReese Is it possible to handle this redirection from the server side using react-router-dom? If I just copy-paste the redirected URL in my browser it works, but the redirection from the back-end is not actually recognized by the front-end

Comment: `react-router-dom` is a clitent-side routing/navigation library. It has nothing at all to do with server-side redirect responses. Without a [mcve] it's rather difficult to say why anything is or isn't working as expected. If a user is getting correctly redirected back to a valid URL where your app is served then I'd expect the app to correctly load and `react-router-dom` to handle routing to the correct page client-side.

Comment: @DrewReese Currently, I have a route <Route path="/account-info/" element = {<AccountInfo /> } /> (react app is running on localhost:3001) and the redirect URL I am receiving from back-end is http://localhost:3001/account-info?code=XeQjmMIno65jDdXiYmn. IF I just copy this redirected URL (http://localhost:3001/account-info?code=XeQjmMIno65jDdXiYmn) and paste it in the URL bar it renders the page correctly, but the redirection from the server side to this URL is throwing 404 not found error in the browser.